# Adding entity to DbSet<T> does not mark entity as Added and thus is not commited

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I've created a sample [repo](https://github.com/MarcusKohnert/EntityNotWrittenToDB) to demo the problem.

**Entities:**

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Attributes
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Attribs { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext Config**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Attributes>()
                .Property<int>("PersonId");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Attributes>()
                .HasKey("PersonId");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Attributes>()
                .HasOne(_ => _.Person)
                .WithOne()
                .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Attributes>()
                .Property(_ => _.Attribs)
                .HasColumnName("Attributes");
}
```

**What works very well for Attributes?**

- Read
- Update
- Delete

**Create does not work.**

Even though a new *Attributes* instance is added to the *DbSet* it's not marked as *Added* and thus not commited to the db. Marking the entity state explicitly as *Added* commits the instance correctly to the db. This explicitness is only necessary for *Attributes*. All other entities in my real project are correctly added through DbSet.Add().

What's wrong with my expectations?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var dbContext = new Context())
    {
        // reading works well
        var readEntity = dbContext.Set<Attributes>()
                                  .First(_ => _.Person.Id == 1);

        Console.WriteLine($"Read entity has attributes value: {readEntity.Attribs}");
    }

    using (var dbContext = new Context())
    {
        var person = dbContext.Set<Person>().First(_ => _.Id == 2);

        var attributes = new Attributes
        {
            Person  = person,
            Attribs = "some"
        };

        var state = dbContext.Set<Attributes>().Add(attributes);
        Console.WriteLine($"State: {state.State}");

        var count = dbContext.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine($"Changes written: {count}");

        if (count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Trying again with explicitly setting entity state to Added.");

            state.State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Added;
            count = dbContext.SaveChanges();

            Console.WriteLine($"Changes written in second try: {count}");
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: This is possibly a bug. I have created https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11919 to investigate it. It seems related to the fact that PersonId is in shadow state. As a workaround, you can create a real property for PersonId, or even a private field called _personId and this should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed workaround by divega works for now.

```
public class Attributes
{
    private int personId; // workaround

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public string Attribs { get; set; }
}
```

Have a look at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11919 to check if bug has been fixed.

Comment: Issue will be fixed in EF Core 2.1